# Udev Rule to Create SymLink to USB Device Through Hub

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I'm trying to create a SymLink to a device that goes through a usb hub which I imagine is causing my problems. I've tried the below udev rules but only the first one finds the device when I plug it in. Though it finds it, it links to /dev/bus/usb/001/020 rather than to /dev/ttyUSB0. What should my rule look like to get the proper SymLink for this device??

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="ttyGpsSerial"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="ttyGpsSerial"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="ttyGpsSerial"
```

Output From "udevadm info --attribute-walk --name /dev/ttyUSB0":

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{latency_timer}=="16"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-4:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="USB <-> Serial Cable"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4':
    KERNELS=="1-4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0800"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="29"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="4"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB <-> Serial Cable"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="FT1RAIYI"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="23"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0415"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.15.0-33-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="16"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1232"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{dbc}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{device}=="0xa12f"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="122"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x31"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x06d9"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized that there is a difference in attributes via the "S". So I can match one level higher along with the specific low-level. So SUBSYSTEM can remain tty but then search ATTRS instead of ATTR.

So I just needed to add this line to a new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/95-custom.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="ttyGpsSerial"
```